# How to keep velocity constant when object travels at peak speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constants, collider

I'm working on a project in Unity 2D for learning purposes. It's a game of Ping Pong. I have its material so it travels faster every time it bounces. The only problem with its material is that its speed gets out of hand and glitches out. I want to find out a way to stop it.

For example, I would like to know how to keep the ball at a constant speed when it hits peak speed, example, 15f. It is a `Rigidbody2d` collider ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in this [post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1035491/how-to-clamp-set-max-value-the-velocity-of-a-2d-ri.html), you could control the velocity of the 
your rigidbody using the `Vector2.ClampMagnitude` method while tracking it in your `OnFixedUpdate()`. **I'm providing the code in the post I'm citing for your convenience. I edited the code I provided from the cited post to match the recent changes in the API:**

```
float maxVelocity = 10;
 void FixedUpdate()
 {
 rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rigidbody2D.velocity, 
  maxVelocity);
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code is outdated, and even when I updated it, it gave me three Unity errors, such as: 

Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for UnityEngine.Vector2.ClampMagnitude(UnityEngine.Vector2, float) has some invalid arguments

Error CS1503: Argument #1 cannot convert float expression to type 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer.

Comment: Changed the code above to match the recent changes in the API. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I replaced the old code with the new code and got 2 of these: error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for `velocity' and no extension method `velocity' of type `UnityEngine.Component' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?; May you have any ideas what's up? Sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: The code above assumes that the variable rigidbody2D is of type RigidBody2D. Is this true in your case?

Comment: Yes. Alright, so I updated the code to the latest AI, which just updated. For anybody that needs, this is the code:

` 
void FixedUpdate()
 {
  GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity, 
   maxVelocity);
 }
`

Comment: Good. You don't need to invoke GetComponent() at every line of code. Just assign its value to a variable as it is inefficient to search every time for the component every time you need it.

Comment: Please mark this answer is the answer if it solved your problem so that other could know in the future